# pytorch bfloat16 epsilon subtraction results in the same result

Tags: pytorch, floating-point, precision

I am trying to sweep some parameters in a very narrow range of values and I use bfloat16 epsilong as the step size to avoid issues such `a-b==a` for very small `b`, however I chanced upon this situation:

```py
import torch
test = torch.Tensor([2.8438]).to(torch.bfloat16)
delta=torch.finfo(torch.bfloat16).eps
test - delta == test
Out[1]: tensor([True])
```

I thought the purpose of the epsilon is to precisely avoid this kind of issues. What am I doing wrong? How can I get the next smallest number? At the moment I am using:

```py
if test - delta == test:
    test = test - delta*2
else:
    test = test - delta
```

And this works, but I am concerned my understanding of the epsilon is not correct..?

Comment: Implementing kludges like this with floating-point is usually the wrong thing to do in the first place. What exactly are you trying to do when you “sweep some parameters into a very narrow range of values”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Pytorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/type_info.html):

> eps | ... |
> The smallest representable number such that 1.0 + eps != 1.0.

As in your example `2.8438` > `2` * `1.0`, it has [exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Internal_representation) greater than the exponent of `1.0`, so `2.8438 + eps` != `2.8438` doesn't hold.

Update. For an arbitrary number, we probably can shift `eps` by the exponent of that number as:

```
import torch
import math

def anyEps(n):
    if n == 0:
        return torch.finfo(torch.bfloat16).eps
    pow2 = 2**math.floor(math.log(abs(n),2))
    return torch.finfo(torch.bfloat16).eps * pow2

test = torch.Tensor([2.8438]).to(torch.bfloat16)
delta = anyEps(test)
test - delta == test
# tensor([False])
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! Is there an easy way to compute the smallest delta given an arbitrary bf16 number?

Comment: I've updated my answer, we probably can shift eps

Comment: Renat, Why `int()` in `int(math.log(n,2))`?  Maybe some _floor_ operation? Is `int` correct when `math.log(n,2)` is less than 0?  `math.log(some_neagtive,2)` is likely another concern.

Comment: Thank you! Great point. Corrected my answer to support 0, negative numbers, and numbers <1

Comment: You have some bracketing issues in your answer but it works.